Can you bust the MDA/DA minima in a non-precision approach when flying the CDFA technique?
Is it true that when flying a non-precision approach flying the CDFA - Continious Descend Final Approach Technique can or shall be used. This allows to treat the MDA as a DA meaning you fly down to a DA and take the continue / go-around decision like in a precision approach, or the MAP - Missed Approach Point, whichever is earlier? In a step down non-precision approach the MDA must not be crossed below and a Missed approach must be executed no later than the MAP. So is it true that technically you will go slightly below the MDA when flying the CDFA technique as the decision is taken at that point not the actual go around meaning you could lose 50ft during that manoeuver. Is it a legal requirement to add a increment to the MDA in that case this is a debate I am having. I have not found anything in the EASA CAT or FAA FAR that require an increment to the MDA/DA when flying the CDFA technique or am I wrong? Nevertheless in the ATPL manual I read I came across the following part when flying GNSS Approaches:

Does such an increment even exist? Is it an actual procedure to add 50ft or an increment to the MDA/DA when using the CDFA technique or not? I have not found anything like this in the SOP of an airline. Technically there would have to be a table for different airplanes, because 50ft would be too generic. Is it done in FAA or EASA is there a difference maybe that I am not aware of?
Following I found in the ICAO DOC. 8168


It's not totally clear what you are asking... "Can you bust the MDA/DA minima in a non-precision approach when flying the CDFA technique?"  By "can", are you asking whether or not you are allowed to bust MDA, (by initiating a missed approach at the MDA) or whether it is possible to bust it if the approach is not planned with a derived DA/H and flown correctly?

@MichaelHall sorry for the confusion, to clarify what I am referring to is the following: Under no circumstance can you go under the MDA unles the required visual requirements are met. However when flying the CDFA technique the minima is treated as a DA meaning the decision is taken at that stage, if a MAP has to be executed, you woul technically go below. I have not found an EASA regulation that requires you to have a derived DA/H and how it is applied exactly...

I understand it quite well, and it is apparent that you do as well.  My question was rhetorical mainly, to prompt you to consider clarifying the intent in the question itself.

Jeppessen charts always include a note that the CDFA requires authorization.  So I believe the exact procedure is not published.
My SOP does include the 50 ft increment on the MDA.
How this gets implemented at other airlines probably depends on the equipment and LOA.
Reference FAA AC 120-108, particularly 6.f, et seq.

This allows to treat the MDA as a DA meaning you fly down to a DA and take the continue / go-around decision like in a precision approach, or the MAP - Missed Approach Point, whichever is earlier?

You are confusing two different things here.  Where the approach course intersects the DA, that is the MAP.  They are not in different places.  However, some chart formats, including Jeppessen, depict more than one MAP to include the LNAV procedure in the diagram.
I have a MAP study guide that may be helpful for this.
Note: There is a nuance to this in the Advisory Circular.  FAA effectively amends the CDFA missed approach procedure with, "Proceed on track to the MAP before accomplishing a turn."  This is for lateral guidance and could require extra planning in the case of "Non-RNAV NPAs" mentioned in that document.  See KDCA LDA-Z Rwy 19 for example.  My SOP does not allow CDFA for Non-RNAV NPAs so that's truly beyond my expertise.

Thanks for your response and study guide. The actual thing that I am trying to figure out is whether the increment is a legal must or only a good thing to do...

@TedStaggs The CDFA requires an LOA and the LOA requires an increment.  This is the realm of procedural standards and administrative inspectors.  It is not a decree of any legislature.

@TedStaggs I added an FAA link in my answer.  It is not going to mention 50 ft anywhere, but it does provide a rough outline for authorization.
